# Как наиболее оптимизировано организовать поиск по товарам в mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Нужно организовать поиск по категориям и названию товаров. Поиск будет начинаться после ввода двух букв в инпут. Были мысли индексировать название товаров и искать по индексам. Но тогда кол-во индексов будет равно кол-во товаров, что интуитивно кажется плохим решением.

Comment: так индексируется же не значение, а название поля. Т.е. 1поле - 1 индекс

Comment: Только начинаю работать с базами, поэтому где то еще туплю. К индексам типа multikey это тоже относиться?

Comment: я, так понимаю, что к `multikey` это не относится - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/

Comment: Допустим я создам индекс multikey, в котором будет несколько значений - категория, и название товара. Если при таком варианте делать поиск по индексам будет ли это хорошим решением?